# simplify UK boundaries breaks geometries or create gaps and overlaps

Tags: postgis

I am trying to simplify uk counties, parishes and districts and avoid slivers and overlaps that creates st_simplifyPreserveTopology, so i have been following [this thread](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiSimplifyWithTopologyExt), I have been going through different similar questions [like this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178/simplifying-adjacent-polygons-using-postgis?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185040/simplify-geometries-but-keep-them-contiguous), but didnt resolve my issue, or still break the geometries.

i.e. [first approach](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiSimplifyPreserveTopology#no1)

```
with poly as (
        select name, (st_dump(geom)).* 
        from new_bdline_county
) select d.name, baz.geom 
 from ( 
        select (st_dump(st_polygonize(distinct geom))).geom as geom
        from (
                select (st_dump(st_simplifyPreserveTopology(st_linemerge(st_union(geom)), 10000))).geom as geom
                from (
                        select st_exteriorRing((st_dumpRings(geom)).geom) as geom
                        from poly
                ) as foo
        ) as bar
) as baz,
poly d
where st_intersects(d.geom, baz.geom)
and st_area(st_intersection(d.geom, baz.geom))/st_area(baz.geom) > 0.5;
```

got this results:

[image]

same with this [this approach](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiSimplifyWithTopologyExt):

Comment: Are these polygons available somewhere for download? or even better: can you share the create table and insert statements of your data set? It is hard to see the issue in such a small image :) cheers

Comment: btw, I've tried this [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=10d9da45a964f33ec8387c80d6187483) in a [GADM](https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/shp/gadm36_GBR_shp.zip) data set and it seems to be working. Can you also test it?

Comment: @JimJones thanks I will try this query, the datasets are available in [OS boundaries](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/products/boundaryline)